# How to Remove a not - html tag - CID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given text like:

```
This is my reply. This is paragraph one.

This is paragraph two. Capture everything before me as this is the last sentence.

[cid:0BE7856F-9507-4AEA-854D-C01A6CFAF15F]
[cid:1DA3C231-846D-4490-9458-04A2484F4294]
[cid:33225087-994A-4FAF-B74D-5D56F334F29D]
```

What's the best way to remove the cid tags, resulting in just:

```
This is my reply. This is paragraph one.

This is paragraph two. Capture everything before me as this is the last sentence.
```

Comment: Something liek this ? body.sub(\[cid:(.*)\], '') ?

Comment: It's usually better to edit your question than to leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch that very specific format you'd do:

```
  regex = /\[cid:[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\]/
  body[0..(body =~ regex).to_i-1]
```

If you want to loosen it up a little you'd do:

```
  body[0..(body =~ /\[cid:/).to_i-1]
```

If you aren't sure there will be content before the [cid declaration then you should pull it out and do this:

```
  regex = # choose your expression
  test = body =~ regex
  body[0..(test.nil? ? -1 : test - 1)]
```

Comment: Whoa whoa, slow down... as a senior developer kinda-guy, I'd rein that first pattern in and say it's a bit too regex-studly. The second pattern is much better for our reality until proven otherwise. And, +1 for using `..` because it's uber-studly to use the flip-flop operator like that. At that point I'd buy you a latte. :-)